# setting focus to first cell of table using html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have table with 3X4 cells i navigate among cells using arrow keys(right,left,up, down) but problem is initially i need to press tab key to get focus to first cell and only after that i will be able to use arrow key to navigate. now my question is how can i set focus to first cell of table so that i can directly use arrow keys to navigate instead use tab first and they arrow keys.

here is my code:

```
function myNav(e,down,left,up,right)
   {
    if (!e) e=window.event;
    var selectArrowKey;
    switch(e.keyCode)
    {
     case 37:

     selectArrowKey = left;
     break;
     case 38:

     selectArrowKey = down;
     break;
     case 39:

     selectArrowKey = right;
     break;
     case 40:

     selectArrowKey = up;
     break;
    }
    if (!selectArrowKey) return;
    var controls = document.getElementsByName(selectArrowKey);
    if (!controls) return;
    if (controls.length != 1) return;
    controls[0].focus();
   }
```

kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page load, retrieve a reference to that cell and call `focus` on it. You haven't shown your markup, so it's hard to give you a concrete example, but for instance if your table has an `id` of "foo":

```
var node = findFirstChild(document.getElementById('foo'), 'TD');
if (node) {
    // get the control within the cell
    node.focus();
}
function findFirstChild(parent, tag) {
    var node, child;

    for (node = parent.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
        if (node.nodeType == 1) { // Element
            if (node.tagName === tag) {
                return node;
            }
            child = findFirstChild(node, tag);
            if (child) {
                return child;
            }
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

In terms of "page load", you can either hook the `window.onload` event (but that happens *very* late), or just put a script element at the bottom of the `body` tag (or anywhere after the table) that does the above. Once the `table` tag is closed, you can access it from script ([ref1](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41), [ref2](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)).

---

**Off-topic**: If you use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries), the code can get a lot simpler. For instance, with jQuery, the above changes to:

```
$("#foo td:first").focus();
```

---

**Update**: Responding to your comment below, your jsFiddle code was:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#mycell td:first").focus();
function myTest(e,down,left,up,right)
{
  if (!e) e=window.event;
  var selectArrowKey;
  switch(e.keyCode)
  {
  case 37:
    // Key links.
    selectArrowKey = left;
    break;
  case 38:
    // Key oben.
    selectArrowKey = down;
    break;
  case 39:
    // Key rechts.
    selectArrowKey = right;
    break;
  case 40:
    // Key unten.
    selectArrowKey = up;
    break;
  }
  if (!selectArrowKey) return;
  var controls = document.getElementsByName(selectArrowKey);
  if (!controls) return;
  if (controls.length != 1) return;
  controls[0].focus();
}
var node = findFirstChild(document.getElementById('mycell'), 'TD');
if (node) {
    // get the control within the cell
    node.focus();
}
function findFirstChild(parent, tag) {
    var node, child;

    for (node = parent.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
        if (node.nodeType == 1) { // Element
            if (node.tagName === tag) {
                return node;
            }
            child = findFirstChild(node, tag);
            if (child) {
                return child;
            }
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="mycell" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td><button name="obenLinks" onkeydown="myTest(event,undefined,undefined,'mitteLinks','obenMitte')"><img src="C:\Documents and Settings\ing12732\Desktop\html_files\tv-dev\image2.png" ></button></td>
  <td><button name="obenMitte" onkeydown="myTest(event,undefined,'obenLinks','mitteMitte','obenRechts')"><img src="C:\Documents and Settings\ing12732\Desktop\html_files\tv-dev\image2.png" ></td>
  <td><button name="obenRechts" onkeydown="myTest(event,undefined,'obenMitte','mitteRechts',undefined)"><img src="C:\Documents and Settings\ing12732\Desktop\html_files\tv-dev\image2.png" ></td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Three issues prevented that fiddle from working:

1. You weren't successfully including jquery. On your system, the path `jquery-1.4.4.js` may give you jQuery, but jsFiddle is obviously not on your system.
2. You're trying to access an element before it's been created. Your first line of script code happens right away, but since the script is *above* the table in the file, it fails because the element isn't there.
3. Your selector is selecting the table cell; I'm guessing you actually want the button.

Separately:

1. The second and third `button` tags weren't closed. The browser probably quietly closes them for you, but one of the first steps in debugging this sort of thign is to make sure your markup is correct and [valid](http://validator.w3.org). Valid markup make a difference.
2. The paths "C:\Documents and Settings\ing12732\Desktop\html_files\tv-dev\image2.png" and the like in the images inside the `button` tags indicate to me that you're trying to do web development without using a web server. **Strongly** recommend using a web server and proper paths, browsers do various things differently when dealing with local files rather than resources loaded via HTTP.
3. Strongly recommend using a `DOCTYPE`. Any `DOCTYPE`, although my preferred one is HTML5's `<!DOCTYPE html>` ([more](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/)).

[Here's a corrected fiddle.](http://www.jsfiddle.net/jAxg9/28/) Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. can you please tell me how jquery libraries can be used

Comment: @rashmi: Check out the jQuery link above for details. There are lots of examples and documentation.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. can you please tell me how jquery libraries can be used here is link http://www.jsfiddle.net/jAxg9/26/ i have actually tried using jquery but could not set focus to first cell. please tell me where am i going wrong

Comment: if you dont mind can i ask one last question please. the above code sets focus to first button. but cant move among buttons using arrow keys which i was able to do before. i have no idea why is it happening so. i am sorry to be so stupid

Comment: @rashmi: I wouldn't normally do this, but I was kind of interested. Assuming your grid is regular (no rowspans or colspans), here's my first cut at a solution -- it doesn't need the buttons to have names at all (although I've left them in, in case you're using the names for something else): http://jsbin.com/iwexo3 (I moved to JSBin; can't stand jsFiddle -- good concept, but too crowded and doesn't play nicely with my browser)

Comment: awesome Crowder. this is what i wanted. thanks alot for your help. i am very much thankful to you :)

Comment: hey crowder how do i do same in javascript. can you give me an example

Comment: @rashmi: It's more work, because jQuery makes that kind of DOM traversal really easy. Basically you'd be using `childNodes` to loop through the children (and grandchildren) of elements, `parentNode` when you're going up (for instance, from a `td` to its `tr`), etc., and you have to check the `nodeType` because there are non-element nodes (text nodes). Details in the DOM specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/